# No module named 'websocket'

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm a fairly new to Python and I am trying to enter the following code:

```
from websocket import create_connection as cc
import json, time
```

I want to look at BTC and LTC stocks in a live feed type-fashion but I keep getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'

I've been looking around and it seems that a common solution is:

```
pip install websocket
```

that just didn't connect with me. Most sites say install this and just have the above code but I have no idea where to install it or what to do with it.

Comment: avoid inline imports!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you need to install pip if you don't have it. Type `pip` in your terminal or cmd to see if it is installed. Or else, install it first by downloading [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and executing it.

Then you do `pip install websocket`, which will install the module for you.

Comment: do i put all of this, including the get-pip.py in the terminal or cmd?

Comment: Go to [this link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) save it locally. Then type in your terminal/cmd, `cd` into the downloaded file's directory, `python get-pip.py`. It should install `pip` for you. Then all you need to do is just `pip install websocket`.

Answer (score 5):

If the `websocket` and `websocket-client` doesn't work, try:

```
pip install websocket_client
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Worked on my machine using

```
pip install "websockets==8.1"
```

Comment: this command working well

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be 2 packages in python 3.7: websocket, and websockets. In my case, I tried to install the former but it had to be the latter. Wasted half an hour of my life on that. People who get here might be in the same bag.

Comment: I tried every combination of pip/pip3 install websocket/websockets/websocket-client/websocket_client, no luck

Answer (score 3):

you can also try

```
pip install websocket-client
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, nothing worked except Pycharm editor showed a suggestion 'install websocket' which worked(in the import line).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pip install websockets` that's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pip, as mentioned it is `pip install websockets`

However, if you are using conda,
use:  `conda install -c conda-forge websockets`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge websockets
```

Answer (score 0):

use `pip3 install websockets`

That works instead of `pip install websockets`