# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

My python version is 3.6. And I am using this tutorial for Statecraft AI (https://pythonprogramming.net/building-neural-network-starcraft-ii-ai-python-sc2-tutorial/). I imported SC2 module from here (https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/python-sc2).

I am facing this error while I run

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named 'websocket'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665760/no-module-named-websocket)

Comment: I already installed web socket using pip install websocket using the above link. But still it couldn't import websocket

Comment: Do u have both python 2.x and 3.x on your machine. if yes try `pip3 install websockets`

Answer (score 2):

try using pip3, it worked for me.

Comment: Use comment section for such short suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to install websockets for this
https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installation

Comment: "This page does not exist yet" after revisiting the link. Link may be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours trying to install and uninstall `websocket` and `websocket-client` but the true module that I need is named `websocket_client`.

```
pip install websocket_client
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install websocket
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Using `sudo` with `pip` is rarely a good idea. Don't mix PyPI packages with system packages.