# Why are the packages that I've installed on Mac OS via terminal returning, ModuleNotFoundError: when attempting to import them via IDLE

Tags: python

Here is an example of what errors I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'

These packages have been installed using Homebrew for talib and pip install Websocket-client & pip install websocket.

Thanks.

Comment: does this solve your problem?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665760/no-module-named-websocket/47666357

Comment: @Aru Unfortunately not, I acutally went there before asking.

Comment: did you run your terminal as admin when using ```pip install websocket``` and try to update pip itself?

Comment: I did, and still no success.

Comment: is your pip and python installed in same direction? do u have issues if you pip install other moudles?

Comment: Thats a good question, how do I confirm? I have been able to install all the modules needed using pip except for talib which I utilized homebrew. I'm just not able to import them via IDLE